# ORA-00936: missing expression -- codeigniter

Tags: oracle, codeigniter

I am trying to get sum of some attributes from the database table,
my code is :

```
$get_result=$this->db->query("SELECT 
            SUM(FOUND_SEED_AMOUNT) as FOUND_SEED_AMOUNT,
            SUM(FOUND_SEED_SALE_PRICE) as FOUND_SEED_SALE_PRICE,
            SUM(CHARGE_AMOUNT) as CHARGE_AMOUNT,
            SUM(OTHER_SOU_REC_AMOUNT) as OTHER_SOU_REC_AMOUNT,
            SUM(TOTAL_OBT_AMOUNT) as TOTAL_OBT_AMOUNT,
            SUM(LOCAL_BANK_DEP_AMOUNT) as LOCAL_BANK_DEP_AMOUNT,
            SUM(TRANS_AMOUNT_HEAD_OFFI) as TRANS_AMOUNT_HEAD_OFFI
            FROM SEEDS_RWM_MONT_INCOME WHERE  FISCAL_YEAR=$fiscal_year AND MONTH=$month
            ");
```

I have tried in this way also

```
$get_result=$this->db->query(" SELECT 
            SUM(FOUND_SEED_AMOUNT) as FOUND_SEED_AMOUNT,
            SUM(FOUND_SEED_SALE_PRICE) as FOUND_SEED_SALE_PRICE,
            SUM(CHARGE_AMOUNT) as CHARGE_AMOUNT,
            SUM(OTHER_SOU_REC_AMOUNT) as OTHER_SOU_REC_AMOUNT,
            SUM(TOTAL_OBT_AMOUNT) as TOTAL_OBT_AMOUNT,
            SUM(LOCAL_BANK_DEP_AMOUNT) as LOCAL_BANK_DEP_AMOUNT,
            SUM(TRANS_AMOUNT_HEAD_OFFI) as TRANS_AMOUNT_HEAD_OFFI
            FROM SEEDS_RWM_MONT_INCOME WHERE FISCAL_YEAR =". $fiscal_year." AND MONTH = ".$month
            );
```

But getting this error:

```
Error Number: 936
ORA-00936: missing expression
```

Query code is

```
SELECT SUM(FOUND_SEED_AMOUNT) as FOUND_SEED_AMOUNT, SUM(FOUND_SEED_SALE_PRICE) as FOUND_SEED_SALE_PRICE, SUM(CHARGE_AMOUNT) as CHARGE_AMOUNT, SUM(OTHER_SOU_REC_AMOUNT) as OTHER_SOU_REC_AMOUNT, SUM(TOTAL_OBT_AMOUNT) as TOTAL_OBT_AMOUNT, SUM(LOCAL_BANK_DEP_AMOUNT) as LOCAL_BANK_DEP_AMOUNT, SUM(TRANS_AMOUNT_HEAD_OFFI) as TRANS_AMOUNT_HEAD_OFFI
FROM SEEDS_RWM_MONT_INCOME
WHERE FISCAL_YEAR =
  AND MONTH =
```

Can anyone help me to find the error!

Answer (score 1):

It's right there at the end:

```
WHERE FISCAL_YEAR =    AND MONTH =
                  ^^^^           ^^^^
```

Looks like your variable contents are empty, or the substitution isn't working out

[image]